# why does image does not display?

Tags: windows, pug, gulp

I am running an angular website using jade/coffeescript and gulp to build. The bizar issue I am facing is that it wont display one of my images(it is a transparent image), this is how it is implemented:

```
  img(src='/images/myimage.png' alt='someimage')
```

The images folder is a folder sitting in the root. When I hit http://localhost/mysite/images/myimage.png it says:

```
Cannot GET /mysite/images/myimage.png
```

Is this a gulp issue? How can I resolve this? Other images in the same directory seems to be working fine. When I open this image from the explorer it shows up fine.

Comment: While using angular.js use ng-src directive.

Comment: If you manually open your browser in `http://localhost/mysite/images/myimage.png` do you see the image? If you don't either your image or your server has a problem, but in all cases this is not related to angularjs nor client code.